# Set Permissions on a Document Library with a Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, office-365

G'day everyone, wondering if someone can help me with this one. I have a workflow that is attached to a list that creates a subsite, and creates a Group for that site, that group has Contribute permissions.

What I need to do is remove Contribute permissions and apply read only permissions to a document library when the site is created....

Any thoughts on how this could be achieved?

Regards

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

I guess, Workflow Impersonation feature will help you here.

Follow these articles,

http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/t/67072.aspx

http://shareapointkiran.blogspot.in/2012/06/addremove-permissions-using-sharepoint.html

Comment: Hi Anuja, thanks for the reply. They are referring to item level permissions. I need to set permissions on the doc library itself.